# How to update value in jdbc?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting exception `java.lang.illegalargumentexception` when I try to update the value of date field. I have a SQL database which have 2 timestamp field format (0000-00-00 00:00:00).

Here is my HTML code:

```
<%=stade%>=2014-01-19 21:43:20.0
<%=edate%>=2014-08-31 01:45:03.0

StartDate</span>
<input type="text" name="sdate" maxlength="25" size="25"id="demo2" value="<%=sdate%>"><a href="javascript:NewCal('demo2','ddmmmyyyy',true,24)"></a>

ExpireDate
<input type="Text" id="demo1" name="edate"maxlength="25" size="25" value="<%=edate%>"><a href="javascript:NewCal('demo1','ddmmmyyyy',true,24)"></a>
                 <
```

I want that if I donot make any change in these field then actual value of edade and sdate insert otherwise updated value inserted

updade.jsp

```
<%
    String edate=request.getParameter("edate");
    String sdate=request.getParameter("sdate");

    try
    {
        String s1;
        String s2;
        Format formatter;
        Date d2=new Date(sdate);
        Date d1 = new Date(edate);
        Date date = new Date();
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        s = formatter.format(date);
        s1 = formatter.format(d1);
        s2=formatter.format(d2);
        out.println("\n"+s1);
        out.println("\n"+s2);
        psmnt= cn.prepareStatement("update Councel set StartDate=?,ExpireDate=? where CouncelRegNo=?");
        psmnt.executeUpdate(); 
        out.println("Student updated successfully");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.print("try not allowed"+e);
    }
%>
```

Comment: put some code and rephrase your question please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
psmnt= cn.prepareStatement("update Councel set StartDate=?,ExpireDate=? where CouncelRegNo=?");
psmnt.executeUpdate();
```

You're preparing a statement with three parameters, but not *setting* any of them.

Additionally, I would suggest *not* treating your timestamps as text - instead, they should be appropriate timestamp/datetime/whatever fields in the database, and you should avoid ever treating them as text. The more string conversions you perform, the more risk there is that you'll mess one of them up.

You should *also* avoid the `Date(String)` constructor, which has been deprecated for years.

Oh, and prefer declaring variables at the point of first use, rather than declaring everything up front and *then* assigning values...